# Limpar Tags Html de uma resultado de um input, com exceção

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como faço para remover todas as tags html de uma string com exceção?
Ex:

```
var exemplo = "<div><p>Leno<span> Sousa</span> <i></i>var exemplo = "<div><p>Leno<span> Sousa</span></p></div>";var exemplo = "<div><p>Leno<span> Sousa</span></p></div>";></div>";
```

e retornar como:

```
var exemplo = "<p>Leno Sousa</p>";
```

como podem observar limpou as tags e ficou somente a tag 'p'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar uma regex com `.replace` que remove todas as tags (JavaScript puro).

Criei uma função que recebe dois parâmetros: a string e a tag que irá ficar, e retorna apenas o texto dentro da tag especificada:

```js
function removeTags(string, excecao){
   return excecao + string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, "").trim() + excecao.replace("<", "</");
}

var exemplo = "<div><p>Leno<span> Sousa</span> <i></i>";

var filtrado = removeTags(exemplo, "<p>");
console.log(filtrado);
```